# Right inverse with minimal spectral radius

Tags: linear-algebra, operator-theory, spectral-theory, spectral-radius

Let $A$ be a right invertible operator acting on a Hilbert space $\mathcal{H}
$. I am trying to find a right inverse of $A$ that has the minimal spectal
radius possible, that is an operator $B$ such that $AB=I$ and $\lim \left\Vert
B^{n}\right\Vert ^{\frac{1}{n}}\leq \lim \left\Vert C^{n}\right\Vert ^{\frac{%
1}{n}}$ for every right inverse $C$ of $A$. I am suspecting that $B$ is
determined by $Im\left( B\right) =\left(ker\left( A\right) \right)
^{\bot }$ but all I can prove in this case is that $\left\Vert B\right\Vert $
is minimal.

Thank you !

Comment: I believe that if $A$ is right-invertible, then $A$ has a closed range, which means that we can use the [Moore-Penrose inverse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moore%E2%80%93Penrose_inverse#Generalizations).

Comment: Yes,  it yealds the operator $B$ with minimal norm, and I don't know if it has minimal specteal radius also.

Comment: Another observation: we have
$$
1 = \|A^nB^n\| \leq \|A^n\| \cdot \|B^n\|,
$$
from which we may conclude that $\frac{1}{\rho(A)}$ is a lower-bound for the spectral radius of $B$.

Comment: we can begin by minimizing $\left\Vert B^{2}\right\Vert$, what do you think ?